# Cannot guarantee the granted role of user

Tags: mongodb

everyone i’m just a newbie to MongoDB. I got this problem, i have granted to the role to a specific user for specific database. But the user doesn’t play their role.

''' "user" : "adminN2",
        "db" : "VuiChoi",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "read",
                        "db" : "VuiChoi"
                }'''

1. This user: has role to read

'''C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin>mongo -u adminN2
MongoDB shell version v4.2.7
Enter password:
connecting to: mongodb://'''

2. login successfully...

''' WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
         Read and write access to data and configuration is '''

3. but…

'''> use VuiChoi
switched to db VuiChoi

> db.VuiChoi.insert({"id":88})
>   WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })'''

4. like i said it can be inserted!!

Can anyone help me pls ? I try to search and then i found that i should enable security in mongod.cfg. But when i edit it , it denied!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't enable [authorization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#security.authorization) on the mongod, it won't restrict what actions a user can take.  It actually won't even mind that they aren't logged in.

It warns you about this every time you connect:

```
** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
**          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
```

Comment: yes. i try to open file mongod.cfg and edit but it denied my change. Can u know how to save it

Comment: Depends on what "denied my change" means.

Comment: #security:
authorization:"enabled"

Comment: so you were able to change the file but got an error when trying to restart the mongod?

Comment: nope when i edit the mongod.cfg (open with WordPad_) and found #security field is leave empty. So i put on  authorization:"enabled" and ctrl +S. But it notification with this: Access to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg was denied

Comment: Ok, that is a file permission error.  First fix the permissions on `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg`, and the security heading will need to be uncommented and the line before authorization, like the example here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/configuration/#security-considerations

Comment: I cannot enable permission on C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg. Maybe i use mongoDB on local host ? i tried to open properties -> security and grant all access. But i cannot save what i change! i tried to save another file (.cfg) at the same C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\ BUT it said contact adminstrator to do that and if i save on another disk like D:\ it success